# Prove that $1^\text{nan} = 1.00$

Tags: floating-point

I know that for most computation involve nan (not a number) the result is a nan itself except for some cases.
For example, $1^{\text{nan}} = 1.00$ which proven by mathematicians to be true.

I tried to find a proof but failed
so my question is how to prove that $1^{\text{nan}} = 1.00$?

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. It is a question of what the IEEE standard specifies that 1**nan be equal to.

Comment: While it is true that the statement cannot be proven by mathematicitions, it can still be derived from certain axioms (or design rules) in IEEE 754 arithmetic. So this is basically a wording problem here. Also the post was to CS and not Math. I think the question is, at its core, legitimate (it should be worded better though, and the OP should perhaps add context ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $1^{\text{nan}}= 1.0$ is *by definition*, and not by proof, more specifically, it is by definition of the standard IEEE 754, **IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic**.

From the definition of floating-point arithmetic, as specified in IEEE 754 revision 2008, *9.2.1 Special values*:

> `pow(+1, y)` is `1` for any `y` (even a quiet NaN).

Here is the full list of special values for `pow`:

> For the pow function (integral exponents get special treatment):
>
> - `pow(x, ±0)` is `1` for any x (even a zero, quiet NaN, or infinity)
> - `pow(±0, y)` is `±∞`s and signals the divideByZero exception for `y` an odd integer `< 0`
> - `pow(±0, −∞)` is `+∞` with no exception
> - `pow(±0, +∞)` is `+0` with no exception
> - `pow(±0, y)` is `+∞` and signals the divideByZero exception for finite `y < 0` and not an odd integer
> - `pow(±0, y)` is `±0` for finite `y > 0` an odd integer
> - `pow(±0, y)` is `+0` for finite `y > 0` and not an odd integer
> - `pow(−1, ±∞)` is `1` with no exception
> - **`pow(+1, y)` is `1` for any `y` (even a quiet NaN)**
> - `pow(x, y)` signals the invalid operation exception for finite `x < 0` and finite non-integer `y`.

Comment: "`pow(−1, ±∞)` is 1" - this one is really weird.

Comment: @Dmitry what makes you say that?

Answer (score 4):

While @Pal GD is correct that it is a definition, it is not an arbitrary definition.

There is a basic rule behind:

> if a function  f(x, y)  has the property for some value  X  that  f(X, y)  is independent of
> y ,  be it finite or infinite,  then that  f(X, NaN)  must be the same as  f(X, y) .

This is from W. Kahan the designer behind the IEEE 754 standard ([see reference](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7866#issuecomment-53079589))

For a discussion why this rule makes sense, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068714/1739884)

If one sticks to this rule one can indeed proof that `1.0^NaN == 1.0`